# How to edit an default Xcode template?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, xcode-template

When I create an NSObject subclass, I always get an empty implementation. There are some things I always put in my code like pragma marks and -dealloc methods. I prefer to just delete stuff that I don't need over writing it with typos from scratch every time I need it. I need -dealloc and -init almost always, but they don't ship with the default template. Is there a way to customize what's in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [article](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2009/05/testing/custom-xcode-template-for-iphone-development) that describes how to create user defined templates in xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I've also created a description on how to do this, this tutorial was based on Xcode 3.2.2 and 3.2.3 (beta at the time of writing):

http://www.sodeso.nl/?p=895