# how to set default comments in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to edit an default Xcode template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285221/how-to-edit-an-default-xcode-template)
>   [How to set ___COPYRIGHT___ in Xcode 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12588846/how-to-set-copyright-in-xcode-4-5)

When we add a new file,

In .h & .m file, there is always a comments/documentation section at top.

example.

```
    //
    //  abc.h
    //  Project name
    //
    //  Created by myname on 06/11/12.
    //
    //
```

How to modify those default comments to :

```
    // File Name: abc.h
    // Created By: myName
    // Created On: 06/11/12.
    // Purpose: 
    // Copyright (c) 2012 mycompany name. All rights reserved.
```

Please do help me on this issue

Comment: @Abizern it's not really a programming question, so they should both be migrated to superuser , IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Xcode 4.5 and above, then follow the below process.

Go to the path of the Xcode. (Right Click on Xcode + Show in Finder).
Right Click to Show Package Contents
Contents->Developer->Library->Xcode->Templates->File Templates->Cocoa.

Select a template. Inside there will be files `___FILEBASENAME___`. Edit that and save it.

Similarly you could edit what are all the templates you required.